# Faster Producer in Producer/Consumer Queue Pattern

Tags: mysql, message-queue, amazon-sqs, producer-consumer

We have a MySQL table which gets about 5 million records written to it daily.

Each record requires a bit of time to process some meta data associated with it. So we have a SINGLE "producer" process which send each record ID to a message queue (SQS).

We then have 50 "consumers" which pull down each ID and conduct the necessary processing tasks.

This pattern works well. However, the volume of data continues to grow. Our single producer can no longer keep up with the amount of data being inserted into the table.

I understand that we can add more consumers to speed up processing. But, what is a good strategy for speeding up the producer without running into ID collisions?

**UPDATE**

Here is the table structure:

```
id  int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT
name varchar(255)   
is_processed tinyint(1)
is_queued   tinyint(1)
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
meta_data   text
```

I would like to have multiple producers running, but don't know how to avoid concurrency problems.

Comment: If you use `AUTO_INCREMENT` as column option you can't get ID collisions

Comment: @RaymondNijland - We are using `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `id` field and that is what is being sent to SQS. My problem is we have a single producer which can only loop through MySQL records so fast. We need to be able to send more IDs to SQS per second.

Comment: your question might be more understandable if you provide table structures (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table`) with some example data and some code?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this approach: [Best practices for multithreaded processing of database records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562780/best-practices-for-multithreaded-processing-of-database-records/568762#568762) - this dispatches sets of records for multiple consumers to pick up. It is much faster than using a queue to process individual records.